# How to store distilled water without introducing impurities?

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

How can I store distilled water without introducing impurities?  I'm going to be doing so electrical studies of pure water and ice and I need a way of keeping the water pure during the experiments.  The water needs to remain relatively pure (I'm not yet entirely sure how relative yet), over at least the course of $1$ day.  What is a good container that won't be leeching any salts or other chemicals into the water?

Comment: You can't leach silicic acids from teflon bottles :)

Comment: Distilled water I know of is sold in PE containers.